# How to avoid other websites to use FRAMESET to our website?

Tags: javascript, iframe, redirect, frameset

I want to add JavaScript that if other websites use `<frameset>` frames, then automatically the page will be redirected to my website.

Here is the code I'm using and it's working well:

```
if ( window.self !== window.top ) {
    window.top.location.href=window.location.href;
}
```

But I got another problem on my website: Some of pages will be redirected to **page not found!**

Like this: http://www.example.com/themes/default/width:100%

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: You need to specify the file and the extension (e.g. index.html). How can we see your example?

Comment: I should not use extension then other pages will be redirected to that extension which is again not found! I need to find a solution to avoid others to use FRAMESET to my website